# Using jQuery hotkeys from within a blurred iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, focus, hotkeys

I'm using jQuery Hotkeys within an iframe (iFrame A), on a page with two iFrames (A and B). When the focus is on A, the hotkeys work great. But I periodically have to click within iFrame B during use of the app.

How can I make the hotkeys work correctly for iFrame A even when it is not in focus?

Comment: Add all the hotkeys events to frame B too? Or better yet, do away with the frames (not always desirable).

Comment: Post some code so people can see

Comment: The hotkeys have to affect elements within iFrame A, and the page loaded in iFrame B is not in my control. I have to use frames because I'm accessing remote websites in iFrame B. It's a research tool to let me monitor other websites essentially.

Comment: Right now the code is not so interesting: it's just jQuery hotkeys in the code for the page loaded in iFrame A. Things like: jQuery(document).bind('keydown', '3', function (evt){ javascript:AddIt(30); return false; });

Comment: If IFrame B is on a different domain, I think security restrictions forbid your parent page from listening for keypresses inside IFrame B.  You'd need to be able to embed script inside the IFrame B and have it post messages to the parent page.

If the user has focus in the parent page, then you can listen for keypresses in the parent page and either trigger the event in IFrame A or call the functionality directly (i.e. copy the hotkeys to the parent page).

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to like repeatedly move focus back to the top frame to create the illusion that it stays in focus? For example, could I do something like onBlur triggers focus to return there? I need to be able to click around and scroll on the remote site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use iframes extensively with hotkeys. I make the hotkeys call a function called 'keyPressed' which determines what to do based on the key combination. If I'm on a page that is commonly loaded in an iframe, I will have the parent of the iframe bind extra hotkeys in the iframe when it loads. The iframe page's keyPressed function will try to pass a hotkey to the parent if it doesn't have a specific purpose. However, this only works if you have control over the iframes (they are part of your site).

```
//handles all key pressed events
function keyPressed(keyname) {
    if (keyname == 'alt+s') {
        SaveStdPage();        
    }
    else if (keyname == 'alt+d') {
        ClickButton('TrashBtn');
    }
    else {
        //Pass hotkey to parent 
        try{
            parent.keyPressed(keyname);
        }
        catch (ex) {
            console.log(keyname);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a good strategy that I didn't think of. I just need to figure out how to inject the code into the remote page I'm loading in the iFrame, which doesn't sound so hard.